# bootstrap, 4 divs, 2 columns. One column not floating right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

It may be easier for ppl to understand with my codepen.

http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/LVddKK

Basically I have four divs. (technically 5 but the fifth is hidden, and designed to swap the order of the 3rd and 4th div when responsive.) But these 4 divs are in two columns.  The problem is that when the top div on the right side becomes larger (height wise) than the two divs on the left side combined, the bottom div on the right side slides over to the left side. However I just want white space on the left side if this effect happens.

here is my html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 start">Start ride For</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right open">Open ride</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 conditions ">rides We have</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right hours">Hours of Operation</div>
```

Here is my css

```
.start { height: 50px; background: #fcc; }
.open { height: 250px; background: #fdb; }
.hours { height: 50px; background: #ffb; }
.hidden { height: 50px; }
.conditions { height: 150px; background: #cfc; }
```

So essentially, I want the hours of operation div to remain underneath the 'open ride' div.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `col-sm-offset-8` to your Hours of Operations div and it should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with this one. I know it probably wasn't a difficult one to solve, but I've been coding all day and starting to lose my precision.

Comment: I just realized by doing it that way, that if the 'open ride' div is smaller, (like 50px) the 'hours' div no longer goes directly underneath the 'open ride' div

Comment: Make a new div and apply `col-sm-offset-8` to that div and wrap it around both Open Ride div and Hours of Operation div. You can remove the `col-sm-offset-8` in the Hours of Operations div.

Comment: The problem that I see with doing that is that the 'open ride' div needs to be on top of the 'rides we have' div when things are condensed (or responsive). (which explains why I have 5 divs, instead of four). It is definitely a challenge, and I think that is what really makes this whole problem difficult. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm still giving you the vote for helping me, but in the process it created an unforeseen issue as well.

Comment: Have the Open Ride div and Start Ride div wrapped in `<div class="row">` and applies the offsets to each div specifically. If problem persists you need to show me what you want to achieve as an end result in mobile and desktop. I can change my answer later on once I understand your problem better.